# Ajax script is not executing after bootstrap validation in JS file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send data to PHP page using JQuery but it is not working... If i write "action" attribute in  tag then it passes the value to PHP process page (img_upload_p.php) but when I try to send it usig Ajax (via img_upload.js) then it not worked... Below given is my code...

In "img_upload.js" file, bootstrap validation working properly but code after that validation is not executing...

*img_upload.php*

```
<form name="frm_add" id="frm_add" action="img_upload_p.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" >
     <input type="file" name="img_upload" id="img_upload">  
</form>
```

*img_upload.js*

```
$(function() {
    $("#frm_add input, #frm_add select, #frm_add textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,

    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        $("#frm_add").on('submit',(function(e) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url: "./image_upload_p.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                var $responseText=JSON.parse(data);
                if($responseText.status == 'SUC')
                {
                    // Success message
                }

                else if($responseText.status == 'ERR')
                {
                    // Fail message
                }
            },
         })
      }));
    },      
});
```

});

*img_upload_p.php*

```
... image upload functionality ...
... database insert query executed ...

$response['status']='ERR';
$response['message']="Submitted Successfully...!!!";
echo json_encode($response);
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `submitSuccess` is a callback, used when a user is attempting to submit a form with valid input. It means that the submit event has been triggered. SO you must remove `$("#frm_add").on('submit',(function(e) {... })` wrapper and perform the ajax request:

```
$("#frm_add input, #frm_add select, #frm_add textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) { 
      $.ajax({...});
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it is still not submitting the pag at all. Please advise.

Comment: Try to add an alert just to make sure that `submitSuccess ` is called.